# MediaWiki magic words expand in a template

Tags: templates, syntax, mediawiki

In MediaWiki, is it possible to expand magic words in the template itself, before the transclusion, but avoiding to hard code them? If yes, how?

Let me clarify the question by an example.

I have a template A with some magic word, e.g. `{{fullpagename}}`, and I want to include it into a page B with `{{TemplateA}}` so that the result on the page B, after rendering, is `TemplateA`.

What for? I would like to have a template **Book** from which I would derive other pages for concrete books, like **HansChristianAndersenFairyTales** and then I would use `{{:HansChristianAndersenFairyTales}}` in the 3rd page **FairyTales** which would return `Hans Christian Anderson, Fairy Tales [[HansChristianAndersenFairyTales|(details)]]`.

I've managed to do the following:

Template Book:

```
{{{author}}}, {{{title}}} /*here I don't know what to put*/
```

Page/Template HansChristianAndersenFairyTales:

```
{{Book
|title=Fairy Tales
|author=Hans Christian Andersen
}}
```

Page FairyTales

```
Hans Christian Andersen, Fairy Tales /*the missing link*/
```

I don't know how to handle the last link inclusion without unnecessary repeating the title of the middle template. Everything seems to be solved if the `{{fullpagename}}` would expand in the middle template... but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Seems pretty pointless, too - you can simply pass in the name:

```
{{Book
| title = Fairy Tales
| author = Hans Christian Andersen
| page = HansChristianAndersenFairyTales
}}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I just tried to avoid unnecessary typing... but if it is not possible, I'll add the 3rd parameter which would be the page name.

Comment: Well, you only need to create the template once so that's not a lot of typing. If you really want to save it, you can use `{{subst:FULLPAGENAME}}` (which you can copy from somewhere as it will be the same in all templates). `subst` makes it get evaluated and replaced when you save the template, instead of when using it.